# Структура maven проекта и git репозитория

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, teamcity

Я хочу создать многомодульный maven-проект. Один модуль - repository - для работы с БД (entity, dao). Остальные модули - проекты, в одном spring-boot, в другом spring-mvc и т.д., они все в качестве зависимости используют модуль repository и имеют разные типы упаковки (war, jar). Кроме этого настроен CI (Jenkins, TeamCity), которые при поступлении коммита в git-репозиторий пересобирают соотсветствующие проекты. Значит, на каждый модуль проекта в maven нужен отдельный git-репозиторий. Но возникает вопрос, как отслеживать успешность сборки всех проектов при изменении какого-то одного модуля, например того же repository. Или у меня изначально неправильный подход к организации всего проекта? Хотелось бы узнать мнение, как правильно это реализуется в реальных проектах, какие еще есть способы управления этим зоопарком?

Comment: не существует "единственно правильного" ответа на этот вопрос. так как сколько людей - столько мнений. попробуйте спросить более конкретный вопрос. но начальном этапе лучше делайте все в одном репозитории и возможно единым монолитом - без модулей.

Comment: Начальный этап уже пройден, проекты отдельно живут каждый в своем maven-приложении и соответственно git-репозитории. Однако изменения в dao модуле происходят регулярно, и это влечет необходимость изменения в остальных проектах, хотелось бы вынести отдельно модуль работы с базой

Comment: на мой взгляд такое разделение на модули приносит больше вреда, чем пользы. модуль нужно выделять в отдельную сущность, если его можно менять независимо от других и/или если он разрабатывается отдельной командой.

Comment: если "модули" живут своей жизнью как отдельные приложения, но есть compile и runtime зависимости, то почему не вынести эти "модули" как артефакты в artifactory и не прописать в pom-файлах всех зависимых проектов соответствующие зависимости?
Простите за тавтологию:)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй создать общий репозиторий на основе [сабмодулей](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8) и настроит сборку на данный репозиторий.